# Potential leak of an object allocated on line …

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory

I am getting contact details and am having memory problems in my shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson method. I followed a tutorial and did this weeks ago but now when I click Product -> Analyze I get 'Potential leak of an object allocated on line' on these 3 lines:

```
[lastName setText:(__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateOfBirth setText:birthday];
```

When clicking on these errors I get (though only number 2 for the third line):

1. Call to a function 'ABRecordCopyValue' returns a Core Foundation object with a + 1 retain count
2. Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of + 1

The full code is shown below:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

[firstName setText:(__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)];

[lastName setText:(__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, yyyy"];
birthday = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:(__bridge NSDate *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonBirthdayProperty)];
[dateOfBirth setText:birthday];
```

Is there a fix around this and how important is it that I do fix it? I have one other potential leak of an object in my code.

A final note: I am using ARC.

Comment: Do you ever release dateFormatter?

Comment: @trumpetlicks I am using ARC so I can't release anything. Putting dateFormatter = nil; after its use didn't remove the warning either

Comment: What about the variable "birthday" where does that come from, where do you declare it, etc...?

Comment: firstname, lastname and birthday are all NSStrings which I had declared at the top of my .m file under all my (at)synthesise properties. Then I tried putting them in .h with (at)property (nonatomic, retain) but made no difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want this:

```
[lastName setText:(__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)];
```

The reason you're seeing the warning from the analyser is that `ABRecordCopyValue` returns a `CFStringRef` with +1 retain count. You're then casting to an `NSString*` but saying to ARC not to take ownership of the object. That means it won't automatically add in the release for you. So you need to tell ARC to take ownership during the cast into Objective-C object land which is done using `__bridge_transfer`.

You could also have done:

```
CFStringRef string = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
[lastName setText:(__bridge NSString *)string];
CFRelease(string);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the answer and the reasoning behind it! Much appreciated :)

Comment: No problem :-). ARC is wonderful but does have some intricacies that you should be aware of like this. Good work on using the analyser - it is your friend!

Answer (score 1):

Since the functions are returning new objects (they have copy in the name) you need to release those objects somehow.

This can be done by calling the appropriate method to release it, or by using `__bridge_transfer` instead of `__bridge`, which instructs ARC to take over the memory management and release it when needed.